# Testing Events in nodejs using Jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine, tdd

I am from Embedded C background and I am not very much familiar with node.js or object oriented programming stuff.
I have written a sample `node.js` application to print `Hello World` and `Bye Bye World` on console and emit events on both the prints using event emitter.

I have following directory structure:

```
TestScripts/  
├── helloworld.js 
├── index.js 
├── node_modules
│   └── jasmine 
├── package.json 
└── spec
    ├── support
    └── TddHelloWorld_spec.js
```

**helloworld.js**

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var SayHello = function() {
    var self = this;

    SayHello.prototype.hello = function(){
        console.log("Hello World");
        if (self.emit) self.emit("SendingHelloToWorld");
    }
    SayHello.prototype.bye = function(){
        console.log("Bye Bye Cruel World!!");
        if (self.emit) self.emit("SendingByeByeToWorld");
    }
}

util.inherits(SayHello, events.EventEmitter);
module.exports = SayHello;
```

**index.js**

```
var HelloWorld = require('./helloworld.js');

var HelloWorldInstance = new HelloWorld();


HelloWorldInstance.on("SendingByeByeToWorld", function(){
    console.log("Got Bye Event");
});

HelloWorldInstance.on("SendingHelloToWorld", function(){
    console.log("Got Hello Event");
});
HelloWorldInstance.hello();
HelloWorldInstance.bye();
```

**TddHelloWorld_spec.js**

```
describe('Call Hello World', function() {
    var HelloWorld = require('../helloworld.js');    
    var HelloWorldInstance = new HelloWorld();


    beforeEach(function(done) {
        done();
    });
    afterEach(function(done) {
        done();
    });

    it('should initialize WiFi via Connman', function(done) {
        HelloWorldInstance.hello();
        done();
    });

    it('should Call bye bye function', function(done) {
        HelloWorldInstance.bye();
        done();
    });
    it('should listen for Event', function() {
        HelloWorldInstance.on("SendingHelloToWorld", function() {
            console.log("Hit Event");
        });
    });

    it('should listen for Event', function() {
        HelloWorldInstance.on("SendingByeByeToWorld", function() {
            console.log("Hit Bye Bye Event");
        });
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testscripts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample Project for Testing",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The issue that I am facing is that when I run my test using `npm test` the test case executes in reverse order, also the execution of test case for event handling is not guaranteed.
If I execute `npm test` again then it might be possible that test case for event handling may get executed but it doesn't execute on every run.
Sometimes test case for event handling gets executed and sometimes it doesn't.

Also, please let me know if I am testing events using jasmine in a right way or not?

This is how I am getting output of tests:
[image: TDDExec]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle your tests together a bit. First attach an event listener, which is the test, then call e.g. `.hello()` to trigger it.

```
describe('Call Hello World', function() {
    var HelloWorld = require('../helloworld.js');    
    var HelloWorldInstance = new HelloWorld();

    it('should emit SendingHelloToWorld', function(done) {
        HelloWorldInstance.on("SendingHelloToWorld", function() {
            console.log("Hit Event");
            done();
        });
        HelloWorldInstance.hello();
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool. Good luck!